# Use lambda/linq on structs

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

I have my constants in a class that looks like this:

```
public partial class CODE
{
    public struct Status
    {
        public const long Registered    = 5;
        public const long Active        = 6;
    }
}
```

I would like to use lambda on the constants (this won't work):

```
var foo = CODE.Status.Where(x=> x > 5);
```

I have made a method that generates a dictionary from my structs which is somewhat close to what I need. The problem is that I don't get any intellisense on the sections. I have to pass them as strings (due to the dynamic datatype).

Is there any way to get my sample above working with my current constant class?

---

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>> GenerateConstants(
List<Type> classTypes)
{
    var ret = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();

    foreach (Type t in classTypes)
    {
        var fields = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

        var structs = t.GetNestedTypes().Where(x => x.IsValueType && 
                                              !x.IsPrimitive && !x.IsEnum);

        foreach (var nestedStruct in structs)
        {
            var innerFields = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

            foreach (var field in nestedStruct.GetFields())
            {
                innerFields.Add(field.Name, field.GetValue(null));
            }

            fields.Add(nestedStruct.Name, innerFields);
        }

        foreach (var field in t.GetFields())
        {
            if (field.FieldType == typeof(long))
            {
                fields.Add(field.Name, field.GetValue(null));
            }
        }

        ret.Add(t.Name, fields);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

---

```
var constants = GenerateConstants(new List<Type> { typeof(CODE) });

var foo = constants.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "CODE");
```

Comment: Your current class/struct/const design doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Maybe describe what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`CODE.Status` would never work, as is it presented in question, cause `Status` is a *type* inside your class and, *not* it's member.

You can think about something like:

```
public partial class CODE
{
    public struct Status
    {
        public static readonly long Registered    = 5; //STATIC
        public static readonly long Active        = 6; //STATIC
    }
}
```

In this way you *can* access those fields, but it's not clear to me if this completely answers your question.

If it's not, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of items that you where you can adress the keys with intellisense I would make something along the following lines:

```
public partial class CODE
{
    public const long Registered    = 5;
    public const long Active        = 6;

    public List<long> StatusList;

    public Status()
    {
        StatusList = new Dictionairy<int, long>();
        StatusList.Add(Registered);
        StatusList.Add(Active);
    }
}
```

Since it's a List you should be able to use Linq and you can use the public const values to check your 'item type' (e.g. if you do a foreach on your list you could use them in if/else statements or a switch inside your loop).

Actual implementation could be fancier (Dictionary with Enumerable as key and long as value), but that would depend on what you want to do with it.